# Replacing a substring with given form with another in C#

Tags: c#, regex, string, substring

Given two strings `s1` and `s2` I would like to replace any occurrence
of the form `s1s3s2` with `s1s4s2`

The use case for me is replacing the substrings of the form `"\textbf\{atext\}"`
with `"\**atext**"`

How can I achieve this in C# ?

Comment: I really don't understand what you're trying to achieve here. How does `s1s4s2` relate to the `atext` issue?

Comment: @StevenV - In this case s1=\textbf\{,s2=\},s4=s3

Comment: Will a regular expression that finds s1*s2 work? You can rebuild the string once you find s1 and s2.

Comment: @SteveGuidi - If I could get the starting index of s1 this would suffice

Comment: There is a syntax to make tokens in a regular expression match as a "group" -- can't remember it right now.  However, once done, the Group type will then give the index of where the group was matched in the string.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.group(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically: take the pattern (containing 3 groups), replace instr with second group from pattern.

```
    private string MyReplace(string inStr, string leaveStr)
    {
        string pattern = @"(.*?)(" + leaveStr + ")(.*)";
        string repl = @"*$2*";

        Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
        return rgx.Replace(inStr, repl);

    }

    string x = MyReplace(@"\textbf\{atext\}", "atext");
    x = MyReplace(@"\textbf\{1\}", "1");
```

full string - group zero ($0)

(.*?) - first group ($1)

(atext) - second group ($2)

(.*) - third group ($3)

Comment: Thank you. In my problem "atext" can change, but I would still like to replace it in a similar manner. For example turn "\textbf{1}" to "\**1**" how can I do this ?

Comment: The input string is up to you. If you use "\textbf{1}" as instr, and "(.*?)(1)(.*)" as pattern you will get the result.

Comment: Not quite sure I understand the downvote on this one.

Comment: Me neither :-D Maybe because it was not a full solution, only the main part of it. I edited to have the full solution to copy-paste. :-P